# Can network admin's stop Outlook 2013 from connecting to free email servers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, proxy-server

I was able, until yesterday, to access my personal email (gmail) through Outlook 2013 just by setting it up as a separate account. As of yesterday it fails to connect to the server.

The company blocks access on the web to all social media and webmail services. I don't know how Outlook works in terms of how it makes it's connections, is the connection something that someone could notice and then block? Or could it be a different issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: it's enough to stop connection to POP/IMAP/SMTP servers different from allowed ones. At University i'm in a similar condition.